# Adding a string to the end of a date input

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a date input I am setting as a directory, but that directory has some text on the end, when I use this code

```
dirname=`echo "$yr_s$mo_s$da_s'con'"`
```

This is the error

```
cp: target ‘/home/tsee/DATA/20160113'con'’ is not a directory
```

Unsure how to go aroudn it, if I remove the quotations around con it simply joins with the $da_s input and makes it unrecognisable from the code above.

Comment: Try curly braces like ${mo_s}

Comment: @fafl then still use the quotations or remove them from the 'con'?

Comment: echo "${yr_s}${mo_s}${da_s}con"

Comment: Do you need echo?  just do dirname="${yr_s}${mo_s}${da_s}con"

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis honestly, I am not sure. I was going off an old script. I am relatively new to bash and script writing with it.

Comment: Curly braces are the best way, but your attempt was pretty close. If you had put your `'con`' after instead of inside the double quotes, it would have worked: ``dirname="$da_s"'con' ``